# Unable to remove action_mailbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby 3.0.3 + Rails 6.1.4. I tried to remove `action_mailbox` (and any unused railties) and have the following in my `application.rb`

```
require_relative "boot"

require "rails"

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
# require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
# require "action_mailer/railtie"
# require "action_mailbox/engine"
# require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
# require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

I also commented out any `action_mailbox` related configs.

Here's the `Gemfile`

```
# gem 'rails', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4' # note this is commented out. I know it's overkill, but this didn't work
gem 'actionpack', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'
gem 'actionview', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'
gem 'activesupport', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'
gem 'railties', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.1'
```

However, when I run `bundle exec derailed bundle:mem`, I still see `action_mailbox`

```
  rails/all: 62.25 MiB
    action_mailbox/engine: 33.3594 MiB
      action_mailbox: 33.3281 MiB
        action_mailbox/mail_ext: 33.2969 MiB
          action_mailbox/mail_ext/address_equality.rb: 31.9375 MiB
            mail/elements/address: 31.9375 MiB
              mail/parsers/address_lists_parser: 31.9063 MiB (Also required by: mail/parsers)
                mail/parsers: 1.7656 MiB
                  mail/parsers/received_parser: 1.1875 MiB
```

I don't think any Gems are depending on it, but is there a way that I can find out?

I tried running `bundle exec gem dependency -R` but I'm not sure if it's very helpful:

```
Gem actionmailbox-6.1.4
  actionpack (= 6.1.4)
  activejob (= 6.1.4)
  activerecord (= 6.1.4)
  activestorage (= 6.1.4)
  activesupport (= 6.1.4)
  mail (>= 2.7.1)
  Used by
    rails-6.1.4 (actionmailbox (= 6.1.4))

Gem rails-6.1.4
  actioncable (= 6.1.4)
  actionmailbox (= 6.1.4)
  actionmailer (= 6.1.4)
  actionpack (= 6.1.4)
  actiontext (= 6.1.4)
  actionview (= 6.1.4)
  activejob (= 6.1.4)
  activemodel (= 6.1.4)
  activerecord (= 6.1.4)
  activestorage (= 6.1.4)
  activesupport (= 6.1.4)
  bundler (>= 1.15.0)
  railties (= 6.1.4)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
```